# nodejs package qs vulnerabilities in strapi Dockerfile build

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, strapi

I am having below vulnerability when I build Strapi through their official multistage production Dockerfile

[image: vulnerability]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine as build
# Installing libvips-dev for sharp Compatability
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev vips-dev > /dev/null 2>&1
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --upgrade libcrypto3 libssl3
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY ./package.json ./
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN npm install --production
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY ./ .
RUN npm run build

FROM node:18-alpine
# Installing libvips-dev for sharp Compatability
RUN apk add --no-cache vips-dev
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && apk add --upgrade libcrypto3 libssl3
ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY --from=build /opt/node_modules ./node_modules
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app ./

RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
USER node

EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Package.json dependencies

```
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi",
    "test": "jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles --runInBand"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.5",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-blob": "^12.14.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-documentation": "^4.7.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.7.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.7.1",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.9.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "strapi-plugin-entity-relationship-chart": "^4.1.0",
    "strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage": "^3.1.3",
    "cacheable-request": "^10.2.7",
    "knex": "^2.4.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "qs":"^6.10.3",
    "yaml": "^2.2.2"
  },
```

When I enter & check in container there are some errors & unmet dependencies.
I tried adding "RUN npm install qs@6.10.3 --production" but it doesnt add the required qs fix

How do I add a patch for qs to fix the vul.